# UglifyJS2 call minify function programmatically

Tags: uglifyjs2

I would like to know if I can call the `minify` main function programmatically.

I am able to run the same code as defined in [compress](http://lisperator.net/uglifyjs/compress), however replacing `UglifyJS.Compressor` with `UglifyJS.minify` does not work.

This is because I would like to pass the same options defined in the README of UglifyJS2, instead of the ones in `compress`.

Please note that I am running the code in Nashorn, and not in Node.js so that would be similar to a browser environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a work in progress: see [this issue](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2/issues/1223) and [this PR](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2/pull/1366).